# Restore headphone pause/play button iTunes opening settings from launchctl?

Tags: macos, audio, headphones, media, fn-key

I think I used the terminal line command [from this page](https://medium.com/@gerswayne/stop-itunes-from-auto-opening-control-spotify-with-your-headphones-and-realize-all-of-your-dreams-63b3637d645e) a while back because iTunes opens when you press the pause button on your headphones on macOS

```
launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.rcd.plist
```

I want to re-enable it now because it also disables the <kbd>F7</kbd>/<kbd>F8</kbd>/<kbd>F9</kbd> media keys.

How do I restore these settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The opposite of `unload` when using `launchctl` is to use `load` on the same command path.

As [explained on this other website](http://help.beatunes.com/kb/troubleshooting/macos-how-do-i-stop-itunes-from-reacting-to-media-keys) that explains that command and its usage, you can undo the command like this:

```
launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.rcd.plist
```

And then run:

```
launchctl start com.apple.rcd
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Solved my problem faster than the time I spent on googling it :)